# How does jQuery store data with .data()?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a little confused how jQuery stores data with `.data()` functions.

Is this something called **expando**?
Or is this using HTML5 Web Storage although I think this is very unlikely?

The documentation says:

> The .data() method allows us to attach data of any type to DOM elements in a way that is safe from circular references and therefore from memory leaks.

As I read about expando, it seems to have a risk of memory leak. Unfortunately my skills are not enough to read and understand jQuery code itself, but I want to know how jQuery stores such data by using `data()`.

- http://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Basically jQuery holds the information you store/retrieve with `data(name, value)/data(name)` and remove with `removeData(name)` in an internal javascript object named `cache`. The rest is just a bit of javascript magic to make it work and keep all the associations right.

Oh and to answer the first part of your question. Neither is it expando nor HTML5 WebStorage.

To correct myself I think jQuery does use expando in one occasion. It sets one attribute on those elements you used `data()` on to store information to them. The attribute name looks like this

```
"jQuery" + now() //e.g. jQuery1268647073375
```

btw. `now()` is an internal function which returns `(new Date).getTime()`

and the value is an `UUID` generated by jQuery.

This way jQuery later on can retrieve the correct associated data from it's internal cache.

So if you are concerned about expando in IE, where I recall you can't delete them, then the leak should be minimal as jQuery only uses 1 expando per element you store data on. Unless you call `data()` on literally 1000s of elements I see no memory problems

Answer (score 1):

Function `data` in `jQuery.fn.extend` is using this statement to save provided variable:

```
jQuery.cache[ id ][ name ] = data;
```

`jQuery.cache` is just a standard object, defined as  `cache: {},` inside jQuery namespace.

So answering your question - I believe jQuery stores data in standard, internal JavaScript object called `cache`.

Oh, and regarding your memory leak question - I really don't know. If JavaScript has some troubles storing references to DOM elements in standard JS object this might be an issue.

Comment: What version is this from. In 1.4.2 there is no such line?

Comment: and btw, even jQuery 1.4.2 is using internal object called cache, so the asnwer is still valid. Slightly different syntax, but same answer.

Comment: I know that it still works similar to this in 1.4.2 I was looking myself at the 1.4.2 version and wondered if I skipped this line somewhere. I know your answer is still very valid

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [metadata plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata) - it extracts metadata from a DOM Element and returns it as an object  (discussed in comments [here](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1404-jQuery-Data-Method-Associates-Data-With-DOM-Elements-SWEET-ASS-SWEET-.htm)).

Answer (score -4):

Its put into cache by the browser locally much like a cookie

```
      from jquery uncompressed:

 if ( data !== undefined ) {
            thisCache[ name ] = data;
        }
```