# javascript: html5 getting and setting data-*

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-data

I've used

```
var activeFilter = $('<li></li>').data('input-id', 'mycustomId');
$('#container').append(activeFilter);
```

Now I need to get the particular < li > element out of multiple < li > elements in known < ul >.

However the obvious selector doesn't work.

```
var existing = $('li[data-input-id=mycustomId]');
alert(existing.length);
```

Useful links:
[.prop() vs .attr()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr)
[How to get, set and select elements with data attributes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13275812/how-to-get-set-and-select-elements-with-data-attributes/13276132#13276132)

***Summary:***

**`.prop()`** sets/gets DOM properties.. e.g. className

**`.attr()`** sets/gets TAG ATTRIBUTES.. e.g. class, thus making selectors **`$('obj[class=xxx]')`** possible.

**`.data()`** sets/gets jQuery internal Cache attributes and doesn't map onto attributes or properties.

*HOWEVER*, in html5 ATTRIBUTES set with **`.attr()`** and containing prefix **`"data-"`** are being correctly accessible with **`.data()`**, BUT NOT VICE VERSA!!

http://jsfiddle.net/wjEvM/

In debugger there is NO property data-input-id listed, but it's accessible through

```
$('#container li:firstchild').data('input-id');
```

The question is how do I get (which selector do I have to use) the li (object i.e.) with given value of dataset, like `obj.getChildWithData('data-id', 'mycustomId');` 
OTHER THAN in a loop checking each li's dataset. Or using *stupid* document.querySelectorAll, because it doesn't do what is needed.

Please explain if applicable if it supposed to work so. Getting data-* attributes set as attributes doesn't allow me to use .data() which is recommended by html5. So I want go get it right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using attribute selector here, this works if you set your HTML5 data as this:

```
activeFilter.attr('data-input-id', 'mycustomId');
```

But, you should acces it using correct synthax:

```
$('#container li:firstchild').data('inputId');
```

And to answer to your comment, you can retrieve it using .filter():

```
var existing = $('li').filter(function(){return $(this).data('inputId') === "mycustomId"});
```

[SEE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Ayg6K/)

Comment: the question is how to get an object with given value, set with .data()

Comment: This.  Goin_13 describes this issue well here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13276132.  Setting the data via jquery like you have done does not actually add a data attribute that you can query.

Comment: @gr9zev If you don't care where your data is stored, then using `.data()` and `.filter()` would work great, but if you want the `data-*` attribute on the DOM node, then you can't use `.data()`, as pointed out by links in my answer and in huwiler's comment.

Comment: @roasted thank you, that's an acceptable solution!! however to set a point on this, what's the real difference between .attr() and .prop() in context of data-*. Can we use both? Must we use the first in favor of second.. any pointers about performance and standatds?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately for your method, jQuery does not store data set via `.data()` in the DOM node's `data` attribute (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446098/how-does-jquery-store-data-with-data)).

Instead, you'll want to set it with [`.attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-value), and then you can use `$('li[data-input-id=mycustomId]')`:

```
$('<li></li>').attr('data-input-id', 'mycustomId');
```

Comment: attr is deprecated by the way. But thanks for a small piece about jquery cache.

Comment: @gr9zev `.attr()` isn't deprecated, its use cases have simply been constrained to be more "within scope", so that it is not misused/confused with `.prop()`. The attr docs explain all of that towards the top, and since the `data` attribute is an actual DOM node attribute, and not a property on the DOM node's object, you should use attr (according to how I'm reading the docs, at least).

Comment: @gr9zev I would love to see where that's documented.

Comment: okay, said that, could you shed some light on the real difference between .prop('data-mydata') and .attr('data-mydata')?

Comment: @gr9zev There's a pretty thorough answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5874652/prop-vs-attr) about `.prop()` vs `.attr()`. I think you're going to want to use `.attr()`, since that will directly set DOM node attributes in the markup, which sounds like what you want to do with `data-*`.